# Does the series $(-1)^nn!/ n^{2n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I used the ratio test and got stuck. What I was left with is 
$\frac{ n^{2n} (n+1)}{(n+1)^{2n+2}}$

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is that $t$?

Comment: It should be $1$.

Comment: *** mistake, put t instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

Here $\{a_n\}= (-1)^n\frac{n!}{n^{2n}}$
Then 
$$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2n+1}}=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{1}{[1+\frac{1}{n}]^n})^2=0. e^{-2}=0 $$

Thus by ratio test it's absolutely convergent , that is, convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$\frac{n!}{n^{2n}} = \frac{n!}{n^n}\times\frac{1}{n^n} \lt \frac{1}{n^n}$$
So the series converges absolutely.

A slightly more interesting problem is to decide the convergence of $\sum\frac{n!}{n^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$|a_{n+1}/a_n|=(n/(n+1))^{2n}1/(n+1)\to0$, so it's convergent.

Or, it's an alternating, decreasing series, so it converges.